# How to show progress bar for few second and then move to activity in android?

Tags: android

I have a activity in which on server response success I want to show a progress bar for few second/minutes and after few minutes dismiss progress bar and then change activity .How can I do that.

here is my code

```
public void conditions() throws JSONException {
        if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Transaction Successful")) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    CProgressBar.getInstance().showProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait while rediecting to website");

                }
            }, 3000);
            CProgressBar.getInstance().hideProgressBar();
            Intent i = new Intent(CDealAppListingDetails.this, CMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem with your code??

Comment: it quikly remove progressbar

Comment: I want to show progressbar for few second and then dismiss progressbar and then show activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int DELAY = 3000;
CProgressBar.getInstance().showProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait while rediecting to website");

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {            
    @Override
    public void run() {
 CProgressBar.getInstance().hideProgressBar();
        Intent i = new Intent(CDealAppListingDetails.this, CMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);                
    }
}, DELAY);
```

Comment: shows error:android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
     CProgressBar.getInstance().showProgressBar(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait while rediecting to website");
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        CProgressBar.getInstance().hideProgressBar();
                        Intent i = new Intent(CDealAppListingDetails.this, CMainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 3000);
```